# entity_get_controller Fatal error

Tags: 7, entities

`entity_get_controller()` is giving me an error when I try to use a class. This class is defined in another file called ingredient.controller.inc

> Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string

The following code doesn't work:

```
 function ingredient_add() {  
   $ingredient = entity_get_controller('ingredient')->create();
   return drupal_get_form('ingredient_add_form',$ingredient);
 }
```

The following one works;

```
function ingredient_add() {  
  $ingredient = (object) array('iid' => '','name' => '',);
  return drupal_get_form('ingredient_add_form',$ingredient);
}
```

The class code is the following one:

```
class IngredientController extends DrupalDefaultEntityController {

    public function create() {
      return (object) array(
        'iid' => '',
        'name' => '',
      );
    }
}

function nutrition_entity_info() {
  $return['ingredient'] = array (
    'label' => t('Ingredient'),
    'controller class' => 'IngredientController',
    'base table' => 'ingredient',
    'uri callback' => 'ingredient_uri',
    'fieldable' => TRUE,
    'entity keys' => array (
      'id' => 'iid',
      'label' => 'name',
    ),
    'static cache' => TRUE,
    'view modes' => array (
      'full' => array (
        'label' => t('Full content'),
        'custom settings' => FALSE,
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => t('Teaser'),
        'custom settings' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $return;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Should the implementation of `hook_entity_info()` be `nutrition_entity_info()` or `ingredient_entity_info()`?

Nutrition is the module name, ingredient the entity I am creating.

---

There was some kind of typo on the code, as it seems to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you haven't implemented [`hook_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7), which is why `entity_get_controller()` returns nothing, and you can't call a method of nothing.

The [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples) has an [issue in the queue](http://drupal.org/node/893842) for an entity example. Give it a read. :-)

Hooks have the module name, so if the module is called nutrition, you'd declare nutrition_entity_info().

Comment: Hi @paul-m. Yes I did declare the hook, but I forgot to paste it. I updated the question. Thanks!